# Why are most scripting languages loosely typed?

Tags: programming-languages, scripting-language

why  most of the scripting languages are loosely typed ? for example

javascript , python , etc ?

Comment: I think you'd get better answers if this were a community wiki (but I don't think you can now that you've posted it; you could with rep > 100). This doesn't really have one right answer.

Answer (score 14):

First of all, there are some issues with your terminology. There is no such thing as a *loosely typed* language and the term *scripting language* is vague too, most commonly referring to so called *dynamic programming languges*.

There is **weak typing** vs. **strong typing** about how rigorously is distinguished between different types (i.e. if `1 + "2"` yields `3` or an error).

And there is **dynamic** vs. **static typing**, which is about *when* type information is determined - while or before running.

So now, what is a *dynamic language*? A language that is interpreted instead of compiled? **Surely not**, since the way a language is run is never some inherent characteristic of the language, but a pure implementation detail. In fact, there can be interpreters and compilers for one-and-the-same language. There is GHC and GHCi for Haskell, even C has the Ch interpreter.

But then, what are dynamic languges? I'd like to define them through how one works with them.

In a dynamic language, you like to rapidly prototype your program and just get it work somehow. What you don't want to do is **formally specifying** the behaviour of your programs, you just want it to behave like intended.

Thus if you write

```
foo = greatFunction(42)
foo.run()
```

in a *scripting language*, you'll simply assume that there is some `greatFunction` taking a number that will returns some object you can `run`. You don't prove this for the compiler in any way - no predetmined types, no `IRunnable` ... . This automatically gets you in the domain of *dynamic typing*.

But there is **type inference** too. Type inference means that in a **statically-typed** language, the compiler does automatically figure out the types for you. The resulting code can be extremely concise but is still statically typed. Take for example

```
square list = map (\x -> x * x) list
```

in Haskell. Haskell figures out all types involved here in advance. We have `list` being a list of numbers, `map` some function that applies some other function to any element of a list and `square` that produces a list of numbers from another list of numbers.

Nonetheless, the compiler can prove that everything works out in advance - the operations anything supports **are** formally specified. Hence, I'd never call Haskell a scripting language though it can reach similar levels of expressiveness (if not more!).

---

So all in all, *scripting languages* are *dynamically typed* because that allows you to prototype a running system without specifying, but *assuming* every single operation involved exists, which is what scripting languages are used for.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand your question. Apart from PHP, VBScript, `COMMAND.COM` and the Unix shell(s) I can't really think of any loosely typed scripting languages.

Some examples of scripting languages which are not loosely typed are Python, Ruby, Mondrian, JavaFXScript, PowerShell, Haskell, Scala, ELisp, Scheme, AutoLisp, Io, Ioke, Seph, Groovy, Fantom, Boo, Cobra, Guile, Slate, Smalltalk, Perl, …

Comment: Ren't Python and Perlo loosely typed?